# Is there a way for a web site to detect an iOS user's "Region Format"?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari, regional-settings

Is there a way for a web site to detect an iOS user's "Region Format"?

Settings > International > Region Format

If so, what is the env variable that's used?

Answer (score 0):

This should snag the locale:

```
window.navigator.language //=> "en-us"
```

In my case, witten language is `en` and the region format is `us`.

This link, on your iPhone, should alert the device locale: http://jsfiddle.net/reHED/

Comment: It seems to get the "en-us" based on Language, and not Region Format. I've tried having the Language in English and changing the Region format, yet it never changes from "en-us".